# getting sound decible in android recorder

Tags: android, voice-recording

i'm trying to develop an android voice recorder.i am able to record and play back the file but the problem is i can't get the decibel of the voice recording.the reason i need it is because i want to show a sound meter that when the app is recording it show's the sound decibel meanwhile.
any idea how can i do it?
Here is my code :

```
    btRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try{
            recorder.start();
                            /**** i need a method like recorder.Volume(); ***/
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {}
```